# how to use field content inside string in mysql json query?

Tags: mysql

is it possible to extract field key inside of string in mysql json query?

something simple as:

```
SELECT json_object(
  'vendorId', s.id
)
FROM vendors v;
```

gives me:

```
{
  "vendorId": 5
}
```

and I want:

```
{
  "vendorId": "5"
}
```

how can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data type cast to a string datatype.

```
SELECT json_object(
  'vendorId', CAST(s.id AS CHAR(255))
)
FROM vendors v
```

or

```
SELECT json_object(
  'vendorId', CAST(s.id AS VARCHAR(255))
)
FROM vendors v
```

**Query**

```
SELECT json_object(
  'vendorId', CAST(1 AS CHAR(255))
)
```

**Result**

```
| json_object(
  'vendorId', CAST(1 AS CHAR(255))
) |
| ------------------------------------------------- |
| {"vendorId": "1"}                                 |
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eBG7GVsSF7gZ1Bwqo2eYhw/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT json_object(
  'vendorId', CONVERT(s.id, char)
)
FROM vendors v;
```

or you can use cast

```
'CAST(s.id as char)
```